# Emacs: list-packages [no match]

Tags: emacs, package, emacs23, elpa

I'm new to Emacs. I'd like to install a package, but doing `M-x package-install` says there is no such command.

Trying to look which packages are installed with `M-x list-packages` does not work either. GNU Emacs manual does not say much about it (or I looked in a wrong place), and I can't quite come up with meaningful keywords for search due to my limited Emacs knowledge.

Comment: did you try M-x package-list-packages?

Comment: The package system is built into Emacs 24, but is a third-party library if you're using Emacs 23.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks phils and shyamupa for setting me on track. Indeed, I am using emacs 23 ("M-x version" to check).

I used instruction from [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs23_install_elpa.html) to install packaging system. I had to copy the following in scratch:

```lisp
(let ((buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously
               "http://tromey.com/elpa/package-install.el")))
  (save-excursion
    (set-buffer buffer)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^$" nil 'move)
    (eval-region (point) (point-max))
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))
```

and then `M-x eval-buffer`

Then, `M-x package-list-packages` works.

UPDATE:

It turns out I was looking for a package in MELPA, and the above procedure sets you up for ELPA only. The content of my .emacs file after installation was following:

```lisp
(when
    (load
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/package.el"))
  (package-initialize))
```

To enable MELPA load I had to replace the contents of package.el with [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=emacs.git;a=blob_plain;hb=ba08b24186711eaeb3748f3d1f23e2c2d9ed0d09;f=lisp/emacs-lisp/package.el) and change .emacs as follows (inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287947/adding-marmalade-as-package-source)):

```lisp
(load (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/elpa/package.el"))
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
```

This did the trick and I got a huge list of packages from MELPA. Hope this will save someone time in future.